# You must add a shared scheme in AppCenter

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio-app-center

I wish to setup AppCenter BuildConfiguration for my GitLab iOS xCode Project.
I get the following error saying that I must add a shared scheme:

[image]

I follow the steps here to generate a scheme for my workspace:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/troubleshooting/ios#no-scheme

The final step says: **Add the .xcscheme file to source control and pushed to your remote repository so that App Center can access it.**

**Question:**

Where is this .xcscheme file located whenever it is generated as I cant seem to find it?
What folder etc should it be in?

Answer (score 5):

Try to share it here, in the "scheme editor". Then see if it shows up in our version control.

[image]

Else, apply any change to your scheme, you should then see file changes in your version control like this. Make sure that the file type is not added to your ignore list (e.g. git ignore).

[image]

Comment: I have checked and 'Shared' is already ticked in "Scheme Editor".  When you say 'see if it shows up in our version control' what am I looking for exactly and where should it show up?

Comment: I updated my answer with more info + screenshots. Please see it again above.

Comment: When I open my xCode project in finder and view the contents of my .scworkspace I do indeed see an .xscheme file present.  But  do not see this in my github source tree.  I do not see it in the gitignore folder either.  Is there a way I can update/push this file to my github source tree?

Comment: Can you see the file on GitHub? If so then it is already added.

Comment: No I cannot see it on github.

Comment: Then its not in the repo, try to make a change in the scheme, tick som box or something, close the scheme editor and see if you have a git change?

Comment: OK I did that and it did not detect the change.  I deleted my github repo and readded it again via xCode but the MyProject.xcworkspace folder contents which contains the scheme does not get pushed up tp github

Comment: Sounds like there is an issue with your repo or git.